# How to set intellisense for react testing library using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, jestjs, react-testing-library

I just downloaded Create-React-App which uses react testing library. I do not get intellisense when I use it's methods (Example : toBeInTheDocument) . How to set intellisense ? Do we have any type definitions for RTL?

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('renders learn react link', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<App />);
  const linkElement = getByText(/learn react/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean [intellisense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense)? Does this help? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense

Comment: Nopes, It's not about VScode, it's about the types pertaining to jest, Which are working fine but no intellisense shown for them.

Comment: Yes, vscode needs the type definitions. Sorry, I meant to mention the types for jest and also include a link to jest for extending matchers since I was unable to find anything related to updating the types for vscode. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectextendmatchers Extending jest doesn't, or hasn't, updated intellisense in vscode though, so perhaps also isn't quite the right solution.

Comment: @DrewReese , So how to make this work. Any steps to configure? I expect the intellisense to be shown and on "Go To Definitions" it must jump to the definition. FYI : I added a new screenshot in the above question.

Comment: yarn add -D @testing-library/jest-dom

Answer (score 3):

You need to import `'@testing-library/jest-dom'`

Comment: And then it just shows "any" when you however over `toBeInTheDocument()` which isn't helpful.